# How to make tooltips visible on clicking an icon and hidden when clicking the same icon?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to show tooltips at three different places when clicking an info icon. And disable the tooltips by clicking the icon once again. How can I achieve this by using HTML and jQuery? Say in the below example, I click Add and it shows me those 3 tooltips, and clicking on Add again hides them.

EDIT : Code that I tried

**HTML**

```html
<div id="info-info">
   <i class="fa fa-info-circle" ></i>
    <div class="tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click">Info 1</div>
    <div class="tip1">Info 2</div>
    <div class="tip2">Info 3</div>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```js
$(".info").click(function(){
 var left = $("i", this).offset().left + ($("i", this).width() / 2) - ($(".tip", this).width() / 2);
        $(".tip", this).toggle();
        $(".tip1", this).toggle()
        $(".tip2", this).toggle();
 });
```

**CSS**

```css
#info-info {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 9px 0px 0px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#info-info .tip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  left: 900px;
  color: #000000;
}

#info-info .tip1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  left: 1px;
  color: #000000;
}

#info-info .tip2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  left: 10px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a place for plain “how can I” questions, that show zero effort. You are supposed to first of all inform yourself, do some proper research, and then try something. We can help if something did not work with what you tried, provided you present the problem properly ([mre]), but we are not here for you to just outsource your work completely.

Comment: You have mistaken. It's not that I have not tried anything or just coming here and asking for my work to get done. Everything is a learning platform and I am here just to learn. Thanks and Sorry.

Comment: No, _you_ are mistaken, if you treat this site as a “here I am, now teach me” platform. Because that’s not what it is. If you actually made any efforts - then you need to show them.

Comment: Edited. Hope it's fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Want like this...

```js
$(function(){
  
  $(".info").click(function(){
    var left = $("img",this).offset().left + ($("img",this).width()/2) - ($(".tip", this).width()/2);
    $(".tip", this).toggle().css({"left":left});
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.info .tip{ 
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info"><img src="http://blog.flattr.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/stackoverflow.png" />
  
  <div class="tip">tool tip text</div>
</div>
```

Source - http://jsfiddle.net/NPXaf/

Comment: Here the tooltip is getting disappeared when we click on the tooltip right? But I don't want it to hide. It should get hidden only while clicking that image again..

Comment: No, the tooltip is going away on 2nd click of the wrapper `info` - because there's no click handler on the tooltip, it's propagating to the parent, which is the wrapper.  Add css `.info { pointer-events:none; }` to remove click from the tooltip

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you'll want to hide/show a set of `absolutely` positioned elements when certain things are clicked (or hovered)

```js
function toggleTips () {
  $(".tooltip").each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hidden")
  })
}

$("#toggle-tips").on("click", function() {
  toggleTips();
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Sans-serif
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead {
  background: lightgray;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

th, td {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px
}

.tooltip {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: normal;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>First Name <span class="tooltip hidden">User's first name</span></th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Phone #</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>0123456789<span class="tooltip hidden">User's phone number</span></td>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="toggle-tips">Toggle Tips</button>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the code in the answer

Comment: Didn't realise this was the form - thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Jack Dunleavy Thanks for the response. Can you guide me with the jQuery code? I have no knowledge of vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: I've update the pen and the snippet above - full disclosure I don't work with JQuery so someone with more experience might tell me it's not quite right!

Comment: Only issue is multiple IDs - IDs need to be unique - easily fixed by changing to a class and using `$(".tooltip")`

Comment: Yeah that's a good point - thanks for the edit (totally didn't realise you could embed full html/js/css snippets in answers)

Comment: Tried the same code in the online editor, but nothing was happening. Do I need to add any specific library?

Comment: It should be self contained - for me I can click `Run code snippet` and it works. To run it elsewhere make sure you source jquery (that's this bit: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`)